# Login Form Error nodejs express, how do i fix it?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

this login form have some problem in it whenever I register and then login with credentials, it always show that my credentials are wrong.

this is auth.js code from controller

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
});

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if( !email || !password ) {
      return res.status(400).render('login', {
        message: 'Please provide an email and password'
      })
    }

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
      console.log(results);
      if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) ) {
        res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
        })
      } else {
        const id = results[0].id;

        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });

        console.log("The token is: " + token);

        const cookieOptions = {
          expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
          ),
          httpOnly: true
        }

        res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions );
        res.status(200).redirect("/");
      }

    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

exports.register = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

  db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    if( results.length > 0 ) {
      return res.render('register', {
        message: 'That email is already in use'
      })
    } else if( password !== passwordConfirm ) {
      return res.render('register', {
        message: 'Passwords do not match'
      });
    }

    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword }, (error, results) => {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(results);
        return res.render('register', {
          message: 'User registered'
        });
      }
    })


  });

}

exports.isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.cookies);
  if( req.cookies.jwt) {
    try {
      //1) verify the token
      const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
      );

      console.log(decoded);

      //2) Check if the user still exists
      db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [decoded.id], (error, result) => {
        console.log(result);

        if(!result) {
          return next();
        }

        req.user = result[0];
        console.log("user is")
        console.log(req.user);
        return next();

      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

exports.logout = async (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('jwt', 'logout', {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2*1000),
    httpOnly: true
  });

  res.status(200).redirect('/');
}
```

and this is app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

dotenv.config({ path: './.env'});

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
});

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

db.connect( (error) => {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log("MYSQL Connected...")
  }
})

//Define Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/pages'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

app.listen(5001, () => {
  console.log("Server started on Port 5001");
})
```

[When entered right credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBCzl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOeNw.png)

whenever i enter credential whether right or wrong it shows this only.

please help me, i am stuck here

I am not sure but I think the problem is in controller/auth.js code and i tried to change the login code in that

Comment: it seems this part fails: `if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) ) {` so try console.log hashed password and the one provided with req.body

Comment: tried this but didnt worked. [this](https://github.com/tehkum/userAuth) is link to this code can you please review it

Comment: I did, that's why I suggested to log it and inspect it, because it seems that bcrypt gives `false` when comparing at this line: https://github.com/tehkum/userAuth/blob/master/controllers/auth.js#L24

Comment: password from database: '$2a$08$ROYV8XexQuXFSXIFVNl1G.OBeow6dLZcANdx35gyFOB'
  

$2a$08$ROYV8XexQuXFSXIFVNl1G.OBeow6dLZcANdx35gyFOB this is the password from entered ..... checked in console

Comment: try hardcoding password.. something fails there, judging by the error message..

Answer (score -1):

Replace question mark with ${email}

```
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =${email}'
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/tehkum/userAuth) **this is link to this code** can you please review it. I have tried your solution and nothing change